# How does springboot-rsocket receive multiple parameters?

Tags: java, spring-boot, rsocket

```
private final RSocketRequester rSocketRequester;

@RequestMapping(path = "/**")
public Publisher<ServerResponse> mockController(ServerWebExchange serverWebExchange) {
    String path = serverWebExchange.getRequest().getPath().toString();
    String method = serverWebExchange.getRequest().getMethodValue();
    return rSocketRequester.route("/mock").data(path).data(method).retrieveMono(ServerResponse.class);
}


@MessageMapping(value = "/mock")
public Mono<ServerResponse> mockService(String path, String method) {
    return Mono.just(new ServerResponse<>(0, "success", path+method));
}
```

If I set more parameters to Rsocket,Rsocket reports an error when I request Controller

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
at io.rsocket.util.ByteBufPayload.sliceData(ByteBufPayload.java:149) ~[rsocket-core-1.0.0-RC5.jar:na]
at org.springframework.messaging.rsocket.PayloadUtils.retainDataAndReleasePayload(PayloadUtils.java:54) ~[spring-messaging-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.messaging.rsocket.annotation.support.MessagingRSocket.retainDataAndReleasePayload(MessagingRSocket.java:186) ~[spring-messaging-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxMapFuseable.java:107) ~[reactor-core-3.3.0.RELEASE.jar:3.3.0.RELEASE]
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxJust$WeakScalarSubscription.request(FluxJust.java:99) ~[reactor-core-3.3.0.RELEASE.jar:3.3.0.RELEASE]
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.request(FluxMapFuseable.java:162) ~[reactor-core-3.3.0.RELEASE.jar:3.3.0.RELEASE]
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeekFuseable$PeekFuseableSubscriber.request(FluxPeekFuseable.java:137) ~[reactor-core-3.3.0.RELEASE.jar:3.3.0.RELEASE]
```

how to resovle it?
This is my rsocket-controller config,could it be a configuration problem?

```
@Bean
RSocket rSocket() {
    return RSocketFactory
            .connect()
            .dataMimeType(MimeTypeUtils.ALL_VALUE)
            .frameDecoder(PayloadDecoder.ZERO_COPY)
            .transport(TcpClientTransport.create(7003))
            .start()
            .block();
}

@Bean
RSocketRequester rSocketRequester(RSocketStrategies rSocketStrategies) {
    return RSocketRequester.builder()
            .rsocketFactory(factory -> factory
                    .dataMimeType(MimeTypeUtils.ALL_VALUE)
                    .frameDecoder(PayloadDecoder.ZERO_COPY))
            .rsocketStrategies(rSocketStrategies)
            .connect(TcpClientTransport.create(7003))
            .retry().block();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

As [explained in the reference documentation for RSocket](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web-reactive.html#rsocket-annot-messagemapping), `@MessageMapping` annotated handler methods can only bind a few things from the incoming message:

- the actual message body
- headers
- some variable from the destination route
- or the requester to send requests to the client

In your sample, the `String path, String method` arguments can't be bound.

Setting multiple data payloads in a `RSocketRequester` request is not supported (I think only the last one will be sent). You should instead create a single object and send it as payload.

When setting up the RSocket, using a `MimeTypeUtils.ALL_VALUE` for the data MIME type won't work. You need to use an actual, concrete MIME type otherwise the framework won't know how to serialize your data.

In general, you should avoid creating manually the RSocket and instead [rely on the Spring infrastructure for that](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web-reactive.html#rsocket-requester).

### Update

In the meantime, the Spring Framework team [improved the API to avoid calling  `data` on the requester multiple times](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/24073).